# Specifying that one set of HTML elements controls a corresponding set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could the following code be made more concise?

**HTML structure**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <ul id="main-nav">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="secondState"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="secondState"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="toggle">
            <div class="secondState"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#main-nav li:eq(0)').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('body section:eq(0)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeIn(600);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($('body section:eq(0) .toggle').hasClass('current')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('body section:eq(0)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeOut(600);
        }
    }
});
$('#main-nav li:eq(1)').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('body section:eq(1)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeIn(600);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($('body section:eq(1) .toggle').hasClass('current')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('body section:eq(1)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeOut(600);
        }
    }
});
$('#main-nav li:eq(2)').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('body section:eq(2)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeIn(600);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($('body section:eq(2) .toggle').hasClass('current')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('body section:eq(2)').find('.secondState').stop().fadeOut(600);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part of the code that changes are the index values. What if you don't specific the index yourself, but use the [indexof()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to let it determ the index itself:

```
var index;
$('#main-nav li').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //alert($(this).index());
        index = $(this).index();
        $('body section:eq(' + index +')').find('.secondState').stop().fadeIn(600);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if ($('body section:eq(' + index +') .toggle').hasClass('current')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('body section:eq(' + index +')').find('.secondState').stop().fadeOut(600);
        }
    }
});
```

I place the index into a variabe so the code doesnt have to determ the index over and over. Now i only fill the index when the mouseenters, because you will have the index of the element were  you entered with.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydXHV/1/)**

I hope this helps.

Comment: well it is not so simple, i added html structure to my question, as you see $(this) cannot reefer to ('#main-nav') i think that index num is the key to optimize this code, and of course your code is not working

Comment: @gidzior wat? `#main-nav` is not quite the same as `#main-nav li`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak well it is obvious, it was my shorthand, sorry for that, nevertheless nkmol example is wrong

Comment: I do apologize. I did not fully acknowledge the code. Check my update!

Comment: this is exactly what i meant, thx a lot for your help and sorry for not completely question